# Integrando biblioteca XAJAX com Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Boa noite, hoje eu programo com a biblioteca `XAJAX` em todos os meus sistemas, mas eu programo em php puro sem frameworks.

De uns tempos pra cá comecei a estudar o framework `Codeigniter` e estou pensando seriamente em começar a utiliza-lo, mas utilizando também a `XAJAX`.

O problema que eu estou tendo é fazer as duas ferramentas funcionarem juntas, depois de muito quebrar a cabeça eu até consegui fazer funcionar, más estou com medo de lá na frente encontrar outros problemas que me faça desistir e perder tempo.

Alguém ai utiliza essas duas ferramentas e pode me falar se elas funcionam bem juntas?

Comment: Euler, qual problema específico você está enfrentando ao utilizar ambos ? Da maneira que está sua pergunta poderá ser fechada por ser principalmente baseadas em opiniões.

Comment: Para fazer as duas bibliotecas funcionarem juntas eu tive que alterar algumas coisas no core do codeigniter, pelos testes que eu fiz parece que esta funcionando. Más queria saber de alguém que utiliza as duas ferramentas o que ele fez para integrar as duas. Quero ver uma solução que ja é utilizada por alguem.

Comment: Tenho medo de ter mexido em alguma coisa no core da framework que prejudique o funcionamento dela em alguma outra coisa.

Comment: Se mudou aluma coisa no core pode dar problema sim. Você não informou o que mudou, fica difícil ajudar...

Comment: Exato, não conseguimos adivinhar como você estendeu o core. O codeigniter tem mecanimos (chamados hooks) para fazer alterações no core (as classes com prefixo `MY_`) . foi isso que você usou?

Comment: Achei um material bacana a respeito desta integração que estou querendo fazer, ele não faz modificações no core. Estou estudando ele e vou começar o projeto do zero. Posso fechar esta questão agora, más se acharem melhor, depois que eu terminar (e testar tudo) posso postar a minha solução aqui. O que acham?